# Unable to display values from dynamic array, ionic 2

Tags: arrays, dynamic, ionic2

I have defined array like this

```
addressData: Array<
{
  title: any, city: any,country: any, 
  locality1: any,locality2: any,state: any, 
  street:any, zip_code:any,icon: any, 
  showDetails: boolean
}> = [];
```

Now i push the values of array like this

```
this.addressData.push
      ({
          title: 'Address',
           city:this.mapDetails.address[0].city,
           country:this.mapDetails.address[0].country,
           locality1:this.mapDetails.address[0].locality1,
           locality2:this.mapDetails.address[0].locality2,
           state:this.mapDetails.address[0].state,
           street:this.mapDetails.address[0].street,
           zip_code:this.mapDetails.address[0].zip_code,
          icon: 'ios-add-circle-outline',
          showDetails: false
        });
```

*mapDetails - contains array object , with object name as address and which is at index 0, hence i am using "this.mapDetails.address[0]" to access values.*

In HTML i am using ngFOr to iterate values like this

```
<ion-item padding *ngFor="let d of addressData" (click)="toggleDetails(d)"><ion-icon color="primary" item-right [name]="d.icon"></ion-icon>
      {{d.title}}
      <div *ngIf="d.showDetails">
        {{d.street}}<br/>
        {{d.locality2}}<br/>
        {{d.city}} - {{d.zip_code}}<br/>
        {{d.state}} - {{d.country}}<br/>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
```

The issue is, the error which I am getting is

> "ModalCmp ionViewPreLoad error: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined"

Help me out with this error please.

Comment: that error means that `this.mapDetails` is undefined so maybe you are setting the items wrong. Try to do a console log of that.

Comment: Thanks For the Help Fernando . I figured out that yesterday and its working yesterday itself.

Comment: glad to hear :)